# How to show only Spatial video using PHPickerFilter in swift 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, phphotolibrary

I want to get only spatial video while open the Photo library in my app. How can I achieve?

One more thing, If I am selecting any video using photo library then how to identify selected video is Spatial Video or not?

self.presentPicker(filter: .videos)

```
/// - Tag: PresentPicker
private func presentPicker(filter: PHPickerFilter?) {
    var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
    
    // Set the filter type according to the user’s selection.
    configuration.filter = filter
    // Set the mode to avoid transcoding, if possible, if your app supports arbitrary image/video encodings.
    configuration.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current
    // Set the selection behavior to respect the user’s selection order.
    configuration.selection = .ordered
    // Set the selection limit to enable multiselection.
    configuration.selectionLimit = 1
    
    let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
    picker.delegate = self
    present(picker, animated: true)
}





func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
        // do something on dismiss
    }
    
    guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider else {return}
    provider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.movie") { url, error in
        guard error == nil else{
            print(error)
            return
        }
        // receiving the video-local-URL / filepath
        guard let url = url else {return}
        // create a new filename
        let fileName = "\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)).\(url.pathExtension)"
        // create new URL
        let newUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + fileName)
        
        print(newUrl)
        print("===========")

    }
}
```